# framework not found FBSDKShareKit for architecture arm64

Tags: swift3, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk, carthage, fbsdksharekit

Xcode doesn't found the framework FBSDKSharekit when i build.
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0tUE.png)

I already have a configuration for Firebase Authentication (Use of FBSKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, Bolt).
And I just need the FBSDKShareKit.

[Dependancies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9cG4.png)

I follow all the installation process for Carthage, but it not working.
And the [search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txl9f.png) is configured.

Xcode run on 9.2 version and Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

**Remove pods and re-install**

There is a problem in Xcode 9 same problem with me...

Comment: But i use Carthage, not Cocoa Pod and i restart the install process two time. Nothing work i think it's a problem with the facebook sdk and Xcode 9 so we can shut wait a fix

Comment: Same problem I got it in my Xcode. just clear your project and try to reinstall and build it again.